# Trying to assign derived class object address to vector of base class pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, containers

I have two classes set up as below

```
class A
{}

class B : A
{}
```

And was trying to have a vector that could hold any object of class A or it's derived types using pointers. I tried to do:

```
vector<A*> objectsvar;

B var1();

objectsvar[0] = var1;

// Also tried = *var1;
```

Is there any way to do this sort of thing? to have a container that can hold any of type A or it's derived classes without loosing anything?

Comment: `B var1();` declares a function taking no parameters and returning `B`; not a variable of type `B`. Drop the parens.

Comment: The vector is empty; `objectsvar[0]` accesses an index out of bounds.

Comment: Read about address-of `&` operator in your favorite C++ textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Unfortunately, as has already been pointed out in the comments, you made several mistakes trying to implement it:

- `B var1();` does not call the default constructor but declares a function.
- To add an element to a vector, use `push_back` (or`insert`, `emplace` or `emplace_back`). In your case, the subscript operater tries to access an element that is not there.
- To get the address of a variable, use `&`. `*` does the exact opposite, it dereferences a pointer.

What you want is:

```
vector<A*> objectsvar;
B var1;
objectsvar.push_back(&var1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **uniform initializer** `{}` instead:

```
B var1{};
```

Saying `B var1();` declares a function in this case.